# how can I sample a signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to sample a signal at 50 Hz and I don't know how to do it.
First of all, I have a signal, I have loaded it into Matlab, and I have normalized it and now I have to sample it and I don't know how.

```
seny=load('señal.mat');
Dato=seny.datos{5};
med=mean(Dato);
des=std(Dato);
[m,n]=size(Dato);
f2=zeros(1,length(Dato));
for i=1:m
    j=dato(i);
    f=j-media;
    f2(i)=f_/des;

end
plot(f2);
```

I have a bit of a mess because when I sampled a signal I had the values ​​of: t, f, w, phase, without (the signal) and with all those values ​​towards a `plot`. Now having a variable with all the data I don't know how to apply it.
Thank you.

Comment: if you need to sample it at a freeuency, you need to know the frequency of the signal.

Comment: the frequency is 50 hz but i don't know which algorithm i have to use

Comment: If the signal is at 50hz and you want to sample it at 50hz, then you dont need tot do anythign because its already 50hz

Comment: OK. but anyway i would like to know how to apply the algorithm to sample the signal, to understand it.

Comment: Your signals is already samples as you can load it from a file, so it must be digitialized already, right? (otherwise, it would be continuous but that wouldn't fit into your PC without an A/D converter, which actually samples your signal;) ). So, probably, you also have a corresponding time vector `t` to your signal, just to `dt = median(diff(t))` and you have the time increment and with `1/dt`, you'll get the frequency

Comment: please provide a minimum working example (nobody can reproduce your code with a data file that only you have...) and help us by cleaning up your code, e.g. by translating variables from Spanish to English